Proof of the Euler characteristic of the real Grassmannian $\mathbf{G}(k, n)$
I'm interested in proving the following statement,
Let $\textbf{G}$(k,n) the real grassmannian and $\chi_{n,k} := \chi(\textbf{G}(k,n))$, where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic, then
$$\chi_{k,n} = \chi_{k-1,n-1} + (-1)^k\chi_{k,n-1}$$
with initial conditions, $\chi_{0,n} = \chi_{n,n} = 1$.
My idea for the proof considers the following things:

Let the Schubert symbol $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \ldots ,\sigma_k)$ for some $k$, then

$$\chi_{k,n} = \sum_\sigma (-1)^{\dim e_\sigma}$$
where $e_\sigma$ is the Schubert cell associated with $\sigma$.

The dimension of $e_\sigma$ is given by,

$$\dim e_\sigma = \sigma_1 - 1 + \sigma_2 - 2 + \ldots + \sigma_k - k$$
I then proceed as follows,
$$\chi_{k,n} = \sum_{\substack{\sigma \\ \sigma_1 = 1}} (-1)^{\dim e_\sigma} + \sum_{\substack{\sigma \\ \sigma_1 \neq 1}} (-1)^{\dim e_\sigma}$$
Then, if $\sigma_1 = 1$,
$$\dim e_\sigma = 1-1 + \sigma_2 - 2 + \ldots  + \sigma_k - k$$
so,
$$\chi_{k,n} = \chi_{k-1,n-1} + \sum_{\substack{\sigma \\ \sigma_1 \neq 1}} (-1)^{\dim e_\sigma}$$
This is where I'm stuck, because I don't know if I've done anything wrong so far. So I also want to stress that my intention is to give an ‘elementary’ proof, because I don't want to use homology tools like the Mayer-Vietoris theorem. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

If $\sigma_1 \ne 1$, then $\sigma' = (\sigma_1 - 1, \dots, \sigma_k - 1)$ exactly runs over the symbols for the Schubert cells of $\mathrm{G}(k, n - 1)$ but $\dim e_{\sigma'} = \dim e_\sigma - k$.
